# Powershell Unable to send Email through Batch file or Cmd prompt or Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, email, powershell, cmd

I've been stuck at this same issue from past 5 days. The script has no issues and is sending email without any issues when executed from ISE directly.

```
@ECHO OFF C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy RemoteSigned -file D:\powershell\Fedex_Meter_Check1.ps1 PAUSE
```

Also tried

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy RemoteSigned -file D:\powershell\Fedex_Meter_Check1.ps1
```

There are no errors when executed from powershell.exe or cmd but no email. Please assist me on this.

```
Send-MailMessage -from 'Trax_FedEx ittraxsupport@xpo.com' -to 'Rahul `Rahul.Lalwani@xpo.com'<#'TRAX ittraxsupport@xpo.com' #> -subject 'Daily Rates `Check for FedEx Meters.' -body 'Perfect! All FedEx Meters Have Good Rates!'` `-Encoding Unicode -port 25 -smtpserver mailhost.cnf.com
```

Comment: Why so many escape characters in that `Send-MailMessage` command? And block commenting mid-command? Looks like it was multiple lines that all got moved to a single line and not cleaned up in the process.

Comment: I also used below and able to send mail from powershell.exe but not when running through as script from powershell.exe using below cmd.

powershell.exe D:\powershell\Script1.ps1 -noexit -executionpolicy Bypass

$emailFrom = "scittraxsupport@xpo.com"

$emailto = "Rahul.lalwani@xpo.com"

$emailCC = "Trax <scitsupporttrax@xpo.com>"

$subject = "Daily Rates Check for FedEx Meters."

$body =  "Perfect! All FedEx Meters Have Good Rates!"

$smtpServer = "mailhost.menlolog.com"

$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)

$smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $body)

Answer (score 0):

I have had numerous issues running Powershell from BAT files in the past. One thing that I remember is that there are weird issues dealing with starting directory. From the command line, try changing the directory to the same directory as the powershell script, and then run it from there. I have this in a BAT file that works as long as the .bat and .ps1 share the same name.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dpn0
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%~dpn0'"
PAUSE
```

Another solution I found in another old script is to run powershell.exe from the .bat or command line and give the .ps1 as a command to powershell instead of as a file.

```
 powershell.exe -command "& {C:\filepath.ps1}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Just adding  `Start-Sleep -Seconds 1` as the last line and it worked for me.